# Jetpack making the Desktop website weird

Tags: woocommerce, jetpack

I am using Jetpack alongside Woocommerce (basically for the mobile theme). I have noticed that whenever the Jetpack plugin is activated, the look and feel of the desktop website changes.For instance, the products carousel just displays a single product. The menu hover doesn't work. The product images doesn't show at all etc. As soon as I deactivate Jetpack, the website goes back to its normal state. I want to use Jetpack, please help.

Comment: Can you try activating a default theme such as Twenty Fifteen and see if the issue continues?

Comment: I managed to solve the issue.I just deactivated all the other plugins, except the mobile theme and it worked like a charm.